# Launching Chromium via Terminal, waiting some times, and close it

Tags: command-line, scripts, google-chrome, suspend, chromium

I've got an issue with my simple command line : 
`chromium-browser www.youtube.com -start-fullscreen; sleep 1m; pkill --oldest chromium`

As you figured out, I would like to launch Chromium with `chromium-browser www.youtube.com -start-fullscreen` (tried it alone and it worked)
Then wait 1Minute with : `sleep 1m`
And then close my browser with `pkill --oldest chromium` (Also tried it alone and it worked). All that from the terminal.

Unfortunately my script doesn't work. It does launch my chromium on `www.youtube.com` but it doesn't close it after one minute.

I believe this can be from the fact that when the browser is launched, the terminal only listen to the software and is not able to execute any more commands, correct ?

So, how can I launch this script so that it would past the browser launch ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, when you run something in the foreground —unless it forks out itself­— it blocks flow. The answer would logically be to stick chromium in the background, and allow the rest of your commands to continue. You can do that with a single `&`

```
chromium-browser ... & sleep 1m; pkill --oldest chromium
```

There are other considerations to think about here when dealing with something as complicated as Chrom{e,ium}. They tend to fork out into monster processes and killing the head might not kill them all. If you're getting any gyp from the above, I'd switch to `killall chromium`.

And that all said, I've just learnt about the `timeout` command. Yeah, still learning. This simplifies the syntax and will even let you leave something in the foreground (useful for interactive terminal stuff).

```
timeout 1m chromium-browser www.youtube.com -start-fullscreen
```

This sends SIGTERM by default but you can tune it. See `man timeout`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So basically, it's the `&` that makes it launch in the background ?

Comment: Yeah. It's still tied to the context it was created in (eg if you ran it from a terminal with & and closed it, it'd close, see `... & disown` for fixing that if that's ever a problem) but it goes off into the background where it won't stop flow.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
chromium-browser www.youtube.com -start-fullscreen &; pid=$!; sleep 1m; kill -15 $pid
```

tested and it works

If you want to be 100% sure it closes, you may be more brutal and do `kill -9 $pid`